# IP address Mismatch between Azure Application Insights and Google Search

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, google-search, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

Why there is a **difference** between the IP address reported by Azure Application Insights and standard Google Search (What is my IP)?

- IP returned by Azure App Insights: xx.xx.xx.0
- IP returned by Google Search:      xx.xx.xx.242

Comment: I don't fully understand what the question is.  Are you saying that a Google Search for your IP address is different from what Application Insights reports as the IP address when browsing your Azure hosted website?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yup, your understanding is correct!

Comment: I can't find anything official on this, but my belief is that Azure drops the last octet for privacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Application Insights uses IP to fetch geo location information such as country/region and city and then discards the last octet of the IP for the privacy reasons.

If geo location information extracted from IP is not enough for the scenarios you'd like to address and you still want/need to send unmasked IP, you'd need to submit it as a custom property on the telemetry item with Application Insights SDK. You can use [Telemetry Initializer](http://apmtips.com/blog/2016/07/05/client-ip-address/) to do that.

```
public class CopyIPTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Location.Ip))
        {
            telemetry.Context.Properties["client-ip"] = telemetry.Context.Location.Ip;
        }
    }
}
```