# ApplicationInsights User Telemetry Without Javascript Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to get user telemetry (like number of unique users) by only configuring application insights to be in ASP.NET Core Startup.cs without adding the telemetry javascript to webpages?

Do requests telemetry enable us to know the number of unique users from both mobile app and webpage or the information about users is limited to applicationinsights javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, binary answer is No.

As client side telemetry need to be captured in client browser - JS option is the only choice. Requests & other telemetry can give you server side data but user specific data still need ai.js

Otherwise you can have audit on your own in addition to your authentication/authorization implementation.

Update:
John & James pointed out some useful info & links to achieve this from server side too.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I thought that AI would be able to determine the unique count of visitors by logging the IP of the request, what do you think?

Comment: http://apmtips.com/blog/2016/07/05/client-ip-address/ says AI does not store any IP address.. and IP changes by fireball will twist the data.  Another good read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#authenticated-users

Comment: You can search for yourself, the expected behavior is different from what you expect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429148/ip-address-mismatch-between-azure-application-insights-and-google-search

Comment: To jump on this train a bit, AI uses the User ID property of the PageView telemetry to determine a unique user. If you want to be clever you can use TrackPageView and set the user id to what your request context user id is. https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/v2.4.0/src/Core/Managed/Shared/TelemetryClient.cs#L505

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you *can do this in a limited way* without javascript.

You'd be limited to whatever information you collect from the inbound requests, which would include location information (derived from client ip address, which will only be used for geolocation, then thrown away), and whatever limited user/session information the server generates for you, and asp.net (including core) does do some of that already.

Application Insights uses the full incoming address (if there is one) to do geolocation, and then (as of ~Feb 2018) throws away the ip address.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't true anymore.

Comment: the inbound ip is still sent, and geolocation still occurs, but yes, now the *entire* ip address is thrown away for GDPR reasons.  if you need IP you now have to collect it yourself.  i'll update the answer, it is still partially accurate.

Comment: Couldn't it track the user on the site using the session cookie?